# Special name for matrices with the same singular values?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, singular-values

Suppose there exist matrices $A \in \Bbb C^{m \times n}$ and $B = U_1 A U_2$, where $U_1 \in \Bbb C^{m \times m}$ and $U_2 \in \Bbb C^{n \times n}$ are unitary matrices (not necessarily related to each other). Then, $A$ and $B$ have the same singular values.

The reason for this is because $A^H A$ and $B^H B$ are related the following way ($A^H$ is the Hermitian transpose of $A$):
$$B^H B = (U_1 A U_2)^H (U_1 A U_2) = U_2^H A^H U_1^H U_1 A U_2 = U_2^H A^H A U_2 = U_2^{-1} (A^H A) U_2$$
Since $A^H A$ and $B^H B$ are similar matrices (by definition), they share the same eigenvalues. Since the singular values of any matrix $M$ are the positive square-roots of the eigenvalues of $M^T M$, $A$ and $B$ have the same singular values.

**Is there a special name relating these types of matrices** (just like "similar matrix" relates $A$ and $B$ with the same eigenvalues)? I know that orthogonally equivalent matrices $C$ and $D = U C U^H$ are kind of similar to this, but $C$ and $D$ are always square, and the two unitary matrices are related as the inverse of one another ($U^H = U^{-1}$). In my problem statement, $A$ and $B$ can be rectangular, and the 2 unitary matrices $U_1$ and $U_2$ don't have to be related to each other (in fact, even their dimensions may differ).

Answer (score 2):

If $B=UAV$ for some unitary matrices $U$ and $V$ (of possibly different sizes), $A$ and $B$ are said to be *unitarily equivalent*. Note that unitary equivalence is really an equivalence relation.

However, beware that quite a lot of authors also use the term "unitarily equivalent" to mean "unitarily similar".

Comment: Doesn't Unitary Equivalence also state that the two unitary matrices are inverses of one another? <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specht%27s_theorem#:~:text=Two%20matrices%20A%20and%20B,that%20B%20%3D%20U%20*AU.&text=Two%20similar%20matrices%20represent%20the,basis%20to%20another%20orthonormal%20basis.>

Comment: @5Pack Please see the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: could you reference an instance in literature where "unitarily equivalent" is defined with 2 unrelated unitary matrices $U$ and $V$?

Comment: @5Pack See for instances Gilbert W. Stewart's *Introduction to Matrix Computations*, Lancaster and Tismenetsky's *The Theory of Matrices with Applications*, Kenneth H. Rosen's (ed.) *Handbook of Linear Algebra*, or Helmut Lütkepohl's *Handbook of Matrices*.

Answer (score 1):

On page 381 of the solutions manual to "Introduction to Linear Algebra" by Gilbert Strang ($5^{th}$ edition), Strang states,

> "The matrices $A$, $Q_1 A Q_2^T$, and $\Sigma$ are all '*isometric'* $=$ sharing the same $\Sigma$.

($Q_1$ and $Q_2$ = unitary, $\Sigma$ = diagonal matrix of singular values)

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but a suggestion: Your question is obviously  very much related to the [Singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) In the SVD a complex matrix  $A$ is written as $A = U M V^*$ with $U$ and $V$ unitary. As your definition is equivalent to saying that the two matrices $A$ and $B$ admit SVD with the same $M$  you could say that your two matrices are SVD-equivalent?